# How to link three comboBoxes with mySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

I have some trouble with linking three jComboBoxes. 
I can link two comboboxes, but when I'm trying to link three I have a problem.

So I have database in MySQL and I'm trying to link three tables for example:

I am a lecturer and I need to get a group list,

1. I want to choose Faculty at the first combobox.
2. Second combobox gets data from database about studies programs in that faculty.
3. Third combobox gets data from database about groups in that studies program from the second combobox choose.

As I told I have done it with two comboboxes. Here is my code:

```
public void Fakultetas(){
String SQL="select * from fakultetas;";
        String reiksmes[]=new String[2];

        try{
            conn.Connection();
            conn.stt=conn.conec1.createStatement();
            conn.rtt=conn.stt.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (conn.rtt.next()){
                reiksmes[0]=conn.rtt.getString(1);
                reiksmes[1]=conn.rtt.getString(3);
                jComboBox1.addItem(reiksmes[0]+"-"+reiksmes[1]);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
        }
}

private void StudijuPrograma(){
        if (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()>0){
        String SQL="select * from studijuprograma where FakultetoID=";
        SQL+="'"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        String reiksmes[]=new String[1];
        try{
            conn.Connection();
            conn.stt=conn.conec1.createStatement();
            conn.rtt=conn.stt.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (conn.rtt.next()){
                reiksmes[0]=conn.rtt.getString(3);
                jComboBox2.addItem(reiksmes[0]);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
        }
        }
    }
private void Grupes(){
        if (jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()>0){
        String SQL="select * from grupė where ProgramosID=";
        SQL+="'"+jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
        String reiksmes[]=new String[1];
        try{
            conn.Connection();
            conn.stt=conn.conec1.createStatement();
            conn.rtt=conn.stt.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (conn.rtt.next()){
                reiksmes[0]=conn.rtt.getString(1);
                jComboBox3.addItem(reiksmes[0]);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
        }
        }
    }
```

I can`t link the third combobox. It doesn't work, doesn't get any values. First two comboboxes work perfectly.

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: I can`t link the third combobox. It doesnt work. Doesnt get any values. First two comboboxes works perfectly.